# Imagemagick text to file batch

Tags: command-line, bash, imagemagick

I want to convert text to images, but the text varies. I would like to make this a batch job. This is my first stab at the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNT=$(ls -f *.jpg *.png *.gif | wc -l)

for f in $( ls *.jpg *.png *.gif ); do

while [ $COUNT -gt 0 ]; do
    echo $f
    REPLY=""
        if [ REPLY="" ]; then
            echo \\n"Text?"
            read REPLY
            convert -pointsize 18 -font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf -fill white -stroke black -strokewidth 1 -draw "text 1,23 '$REPLY'" $f a
        fi
    COUNT=$((COUNT-1))
done

done
```

The number of times I want to do this varies depending on the total number of files. $REPLY is line to write to the image.

The problem is that filenames here is that numbers and source and target files are always the same (here the target is a).

edit: I should explain this by example: I have pictures of cat, dog and elephant. On all pictures I want write name of the animal. But next time I have pictures of bear, cat. deer, dog and elephant. And I want to write bear, meow (cat), deer, wuff wuff (dog) and matt or carl or foo (elephant).

Hopefully this explains little of what I want. Point is tha total number of files alternates and text to write to them will be asked.

Comment: Did you try it? let we know if it functions.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** after edit: In the hope I understood well this time...

This script should function.
It will print you errors on the screen if there are not png, jpg or gif images.
It will prompt to ask for a text, if not entered it will skip to next, if entered will add the text and create image in the OutputDir.
You can choose (un-commenting the respective line) among 3 way to change name.

```
#!/bin/bash
OutputDir="Image_With_Text"   # We will put the new images elsewhere (more clean)
mkdir -p $OutputDir           # It creates the dir, if exists it will give no error
for f in $( ls *.jpg *.png *.gif ); do
    printf "# We work on file: $f \n# Enter text or press return to skip:"
    read -r  REPLY
        if [ ! "$REPLY" == "" ]; then
            # Uncomment one of the next 3 options (The last uncommented will work)
            # NewFile=$OutputDir"/Texted."$f         # Here to have a fixed prefix in new name 
            # NewFile=$OutputDir"/"${REPLY}.${f##*.} # Here to have text_inserted.oldname.extention
            NewFile=$OutputDir"/"${REPLY}.$f         # Here to have text_inserted.oldextention (gif,png...)
            printf "# We add text \"$REPLY\" to the file $f\n# $f  --> $NewFile \n\n"
            convert -pointsize 18 -font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf -fill white -stroke black -strokewidth 1 -draw "text 1,23 '$REPLY'" $f "$NewFile"
        else 
            printf "# We skip the file $f \n\n"
        fi
done 
printf "\n *** DONE *** \n\n"
```

---

I suppose your original script would not work like you think `:-)` because you nest 2 loop.
Give it a look to the [last comment of this answer](https://superuser.com/a/759388/257269)

If you get rid of the loop `while [ $COUNT -gt 0 ]; do` ... `done`,
the minimal modification should be to add  after the line with `convert ...` 
something like

```
mv a "With_Text."$f
```

e.g If the file was named `cat.gif` the new one will be renamed `With_Text.cat.gif`

---

I cannot understand the last sentence. From the history of your question I guess that you want to read from a text file the lines that you are typing by keyboard.

If it is so it's enough to execute your script with this command

```
/bin/bash Myscript.sh  < File_With_Text.txt
```

where the file `File_With_Text.txt` is the one in which you write the lines.