# bash: Use columns separate in an array

Tags: linux, bash-scripting

Is it possible to put columns separate in arrays, not as a line but as a column. I need to access the lines sequentially. I have one file, but in this example, the files are divided into columns and used separately.

example file:

```
column1  column2  column3
  444      999      000                 
  555      888      xxx 
  666      777      xxx
```

output file:

```
output is 444  bla  999  bla  000                   
output is 555  bla  888  bla  xxx   
output is 666  bla  777  bla  xxx
```

What I tried is the following bash:

```
readarray -t column <firstcolumn.txt
for i in "${column1[@]}";  do
    readarray -t  column2 <secondcolumn.txt
    for j in "${column2[@]}"; do
        readarray -t column3 <thirdcolumn.txt
        for k in "${column3[@]}";  do
            echo "output is $i bla $j bla $k"
        done
    done
 done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple script that should show the use of `readarray`.
I keep it more similar I could to the one you post.

```
#!/bin/bash 

awk '{ print $1 }' data.txt  >  file_column1.txt
awk '{ print $2 }' data.txt  >  file_column2.txt
awk '{ print $3 }' data.txt  >  file_column3.txt
# NLines=` wc -l data.txt | awk '{print $1}'`

readarray -t column1 < file_column1.txt
readarray -t column2 < file_column2.txt
readarray -t column3 < file_column3.txt

i=0;
for item in "${column1[@]}"; do
   echo  output is ${column1[$i]} bla ${column2[$i]}  bla ${column3[$i]}; 
   let "i=i+1" 
done

# rm -f file_column1.txt file_column2.txt file_column3.txt
```

**Comments**:

- With `awk` you can print the column you desire (`$1`for the 1st, `$2` the 2nd and so on).You create a different file for every column.
- If uncommented the line `#Nlines=wc -l | awk '{print $1}'` could be used to keep count of the number of lines for the vector that will created after with `readarray`, and to do the loop in a different way...
- With `readarray` you read the single file and you put in a 1D vector.
- The loop `for` is made on for each component of the 1D vector column1. It should be done taking each vector because in your example they have all the same size. It should be done using `Nlines`.
- In the **not used** variable `item` inside the loop there is always the same value of column1[i]
- You access **directly** the component you want of the array.(The first index is `0` and the last is `Nlines-1`)
- You increase the value of `i` at each iteration of the `for` loop.
- If needed uncomment to erase the temporary files created in the script.

The output is

```
 output is 444 bla 999  bla 000 
 output is 555 bla 888  bla xxx 
 output is 666 bla 777  bla xxx
```

**Last comment**
If you nest 3 loop (one inside the other) you'll obtain each permutation: not 3 but 3*3*3=27 lines

```
 0 0 0  
 0 0 1   
 0 0 2   
 0 1 0  
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you load the arrays separately from the operation in which you print them?

```
readarray -t column1 <column1.txt
readarray -t column2 <column2.txt
readarray -t column3 <column3.txt

for (( i=0; i<${#column1[@]}; i++ )); do
    echo -e "output is ${column1[$i]} bla ${column2[$i]} bla ${column3[$i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, you seem to be asking for one thing but your output shows another. To get your desired output, all you need is

```
while read col1 col2 col3; do
    echo "output is $col1  bla  $col2  bla  $col3"
done < file
```

Or, to skip the header:

```
tail -n +2 file | while read col1 col2 col3; do     
    echo "output is $col1  bla  $col2  bla  $col3"; 
done
```

If you really need them in an array, try something like

```
i=0; 
while read col1 col2 col3; do 
    col1s[$i]=$col1; 
    col2s[$i]=$col2; 
    col3s[$i]=$col3; 
    let i++; 
done < <(tail -n +2 file); 
k=0;
for(( k=0; k<i; k++ )); do 
    echo "output is ${col1s[$k]} blah ${col2s[$k]} blah ${col3s[$k]}"; 
done
```